# Finding Triples...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Not sure where to start...

Find all triples $(m,n,p)$ which satisfy the equation
$$p^n+3600=m^2$$ where $p$ is prime and $m,n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's $p^n=(m+60)(m-60)$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228241/solving-a-diophantine-equation-pn144-m2) is a related question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$p^n=(m+60)(m-60)$$
Let $$m+60=(p^a)$$ and $$m-60=(p^b)$$
Where $0\leq b <a$

Now $$p^a-p^b=120$$

Given the above result, we have two main cases:

- $b=0 \therefore n=a$
- $b>0 \therefore n=a+b$ $(a+1\le n\le 2a-1)$

In the first case $p^a=121$, from which $p=11,n=a=2$.

In the second case $p$ must divide $120$ and thus $\in\{2,3,5\}$. If $p=2$, then

$8|120=2^a-2^b,$

where $8$ is the largest power of $2$ having this divisibility. This forces

$b=3, 2^a=128,a=7,$

thus $n=a+b=10$. By similar logic $p=3$ requires $b=1,3^a=123$ which has no solution; and $p=5$ gives

$b=1,5^a=125, a=3,n=4.$

Thus the complete solution set:

$11^2+3600=61^2$

$2^{10}+3600=68^2$

$5^4+3600=65^2.$

Answer (score 5):

Since $p^n=(m+60)(m-60)$, we cannot have $n=1$ (justify!)

If one of the above factors is $1$, then $(m,n,p)=(61,2,11)$ is the only possible solution (justify!)

If not, then assume $n\ge 2$ and hence $m+60=p^{k_1}$, $m-60=p^{k_2}$ which gives $2m=p^{k_1}+p^{k_2}$ and hence $p|m$ so that $p^2|m^2$. Using this in the original equation, $p^2|3600$. Check these (few) cases separately.

Comment: @Stef that is true, I don't know why I wrote that!